# Pickle "EOFError: Ran out of input" in try-except statement

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pickle

I am working in a Jupyter notebook with Python 3.8.5 and IPython 7.19.0.

I have saved some data in files that appear in `jes_file_list`. Much of the data comes from an older version of my code and has 5 arguments. The following code ("the older version") successfully loads the data from these 5-variable files:

```
jes = NP.zeros((ne,ns,nw))
num_deltas = NP.zeros((ne,ns,nw))
w_index = 0
for file in jes_file_list:
        with open(filename, "rb") as infile:
            jes[:,:,w_index], emin, emax, smin, smax = pickle.load(infile)
        w_index += 1
```

Recently I've added to the code so that these files produce a little more output, so some of the file have a sixth variable I'd like to load. For that, I've changed the code to this ("the new code"):

```
jes = NP.zeros((ne,ns,nw))
num_deltas = NP.zeros((ne,ns,nw))
w_index = 0
for file in jes_file_list:
        with open(filename, "rb") as infile:
            # Old jes files do not have num_deltas, so be prepared to load a file without it
            try:
                jes[:,:,w_index], emin, emax, smin, smax, num_deltas[:,:,w_index] = pickle.load(infile)
            except:
                jes[:,:,w_index], emin, emax, smin, smax = pickle.load(infile)
        w_index += 1
```

The new code successfully loads the new 6-variable files. However, if fails to load 5-variable files in spite of the try-except statement. As it should, it catches the `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 5)` exception, but then when it tries to run `jes[:,:,w_index], emin, emax, smin, smax = pickle.load(infile)` in the except part of the statement, it throws me an error `EOFError: Ran out of input`.

Why is this? The file is clearly not empty, as I can revert the code back to the old version by deleting a few lines. Obviously, though, this is not the ideal solution.

EDIT:
By also putting the with statement in both try-except cases, the error is avoided and I've got the compatibility I desired with minimal redundant code.

```
try:
    with open(jes_comb_path+"/"+file, "rb") as infile:
        jes_temp, emin, emax, smin, smax, num_deltas[:,:,w_index] = pickle.load(infile)
except:
    with open(jes_comb_path+"/"+file, "rb") as infile:
        jes_temp, emin, emax, smin, smax = pickle.load(infile)
jes[:,:,w_index] = jes_temp
```

I guess this is a peculiarity of how files are opened that at this point I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: The first time you executed `pickle.load(infile)`, it *read the entire file* - the failure due to unpacking the wrong number of elements still lies in the future.  If you try to execute `pickle.load(infile)` again, nothing gets read, because the current position is at the end of the file.  Reopening the file would work, as you discovered; so would rewinding the file via `infile.seek(0)` before the second read attempt.  Or you could just read the file once - `contents = pickle.load(infile)` perhaps - and make two attempts to unpack `contents` into your five or six variables.

Comment: Ah, I see - thank you! This explains it.